# How to remove users from itunes, with whom You have an agreement

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, itunes, itunes-store

I've a developer added to my apple account whom I want to remove. I've an agreement with him on itunes so when I remove him from itunes connect he doesn't get removed from account settings.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try SuperUser or Ask Different. This is off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: Well, I'm superuser. thanks anyway